# Issue with Raspberry Pi and VNC Viewer

Tags: pi-3, vnc, connection

I am using a Raspberry PI 3 and am trying to connect it with my laptop using VNC viewer. My Raspberry PI has not been able to connect with VNC viewer since the last 2 to 3 days after I changed the network which it uses for connection. Before that, I was able to connect it with my VNC viewer. Now it shows me the connecting screen only (attached below).

[image: Screenshot of the issue]

Please help me out if anyone knows the solution for this problem

Comment: When you said you "changed the network" - that is too ambiguous.  What exactly did you change?  Also, you're just saying what is wrong, and not what you have done.  But, with that being said - have you tried `sudo raspi-config` > Interface Options > Ensure VNC is enabled, and reboot?

Comment: @Sanders Basically I connect my Raspberry Pi to WiFi shared via Hotspot of my phone. VNC used to connect properly until i changed the sim..